# CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical doesn't point to north

Tags: objective-c, core-motion

I am using this code to define the device position. Roll & pitch values looks good(they are 0 when device is on the table), but when yaw is 0, compass points to west. What's wrong?

```
        [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                                   withHandler: ^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error){
                                                       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleDeviceMotion:) withObject:motion waitUntilDone:YES];
                                                   }];
    }
}

- (void)handleDeviceMotion:(CMDeviceMotion*)motion {
   CMAttitude *attitude = motion.attitude;
   double yaw = attitude.yaw * 180 / M_PI;
   double pitch = attitude.pitch * 180 / M_PI;
   double roll = attitude.roll * 180 / M_PI;
   self.xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%7.4f", yaw];
   self.yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%7.4f", pitch];
   self.zLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%7.4f", roll];
   [self sendDeviceAttitudeLogWithYaw:yaw pitch:pitch roll:roll];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> When yaw is 0, phone must point to north, no?

What do you mean by "phone"? The question is, what *part* of the phone. Let's read the docs:

> `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical`
>
> Describes a reference frame in which the Z axis is vertical and the X axis points toward true north.

The X axis runs out the right side of the device. So you should expect yaw to be 0 when the right side of the device is north.

Comment: Thank you for perfect description! Now I understand.

Comment: This is brilliant! I turned on compass app on my iPad and always find there's a 90° gap between north and the head of phone.